# Android Application: Stop using Deprecated API's on new API level enabled device

Tags: android, api, google-play, apk

Well we started an application with support from API Level 8 i.e Froyo verison. Now we being on API level 18 Jelly Bean version, how do we stop using deprecated API's on my application.

One Example

Dialog(API 1) vs DialogFragment(API 13)

Following are in my mind

1)Use [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) Good way to go?

2)Have a runtime API level check as below, is this a healthy habit?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES) {//Some API Level
run a code
}else if(){
run a code
}
```

3) Use reflection?

4)Have separate code base to each API level,makes no sense.

5)Does Palystore allows us to uplaod multiple Apk's based on API level.Or the complete control is on uses-sdk manifest value.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

What will be the best way use latest API's with only one code base and make one APK and inturn have backward comparability support.

Inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would use 2 by a factory

Comment: You may also want to consider raising the minimum SDK you support. [FroYo only holds a 2.2% market share](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). You likely could raise the minimum version to API 10 (2.3, Gingerbread) without losing many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One Example Dialog(API 1) vs DialogFragment(API 13)

[`Dialog` is not deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). Ways of *using* `Dialog` may be deprecated, such as the old-style managed dialogs.

> Use Android Support Library Good way to go?

Generally, yes.

> Have a runtime API level check as below, is this a healthy habit?

Yes, though usually you use `>=` or `<=`, not `==`, to drive behaviors for a range of API levels.

> Use reflection?

I wouldn't.

> Have separate code base to each API level,makes no sense. 
>   Does Palystore allows us to uplaod multiple Apk's based on API level

In some extreme cases this may be required. Most apps should not need this.

> What will be the best way use latest API's with only one code base and make one APK and inturn have backward comparability support.

That is impossible to answer in the abstract.

Comment: @CommmonsWare tanx for the inputs.just had look on this http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html What do you say?Run time check is what android guys suggest. With respect to dialogs i was talking about "removeDialog(int id)
This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package."

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: The documentation agrees with what I wrote. `removeDialog()` is part of the old-style managed dialogs pattern.

Comment: Agreed..Whats your take on http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html ?

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: Um, I think it is documentation. :-) Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Why not upload the existing application as a "legacy version" of the application, that supports older version of the app, and continue to develop the existing application for newer devices?